# How to send a parameter in data attribute of $.ajax() function in following scenario?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, argument-passing

I've written one AJAX function code as follows :

```
$('#form').submit(function(e) {
  var form = $(this);
  var formdata = false;
  if(window.FormData) {
    formdata = new FormData(form[0]);
  }

  var formAction = form.attr('action');

  $.ajax({
    type        : 'POST',
    url         : 'manufacturers.php',
    cache       : false,
    data        : formdata ? formdata : form.serialize(),
    contentType : false,
    processData : false,

    success: function(response) {
      if(response != 'error') {
        //$('#messages').addClass('alert alert-success').text(response);
        // OP requested to close the modal
        $('#myModal').modal('hide');
      } else {
        $('#messages').addClass('alert alert-danger').text(response);
      }
    }
  });
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Now here in data attribute I want to send some additional parameters with values in data attribute. How should I send these parameters to PHP file?

For clear understanding of my issue refer the following AJAX function code that I've written previously :

```
function GetPaymentRequest(status){
     var status = $('#status_filter').val();
     $.ajax({ 
      type: "POST",
      url: "view_payment_request.php",
      data: {'op':'payment_request_by_status','request_status':status},  

      success: function(data) {
      // alert(data);

        }

    });
 }
```

In above function code you can see that I've passed few parameters with values viz. **'op':'payment_request_by_status','request_status':status** in data attribute.

Exactly same parameters I want to pass in first AJAX function code. The already mentioned parameter "formdata ? formdata : form.serialize()" should also be there.

How should I do this? Can someone please help me in this regard?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Refer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19438937/passing-data-with-jquery-ajax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add by using [**$.param**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/)

```
form.serialize() + '&' + $.param({'op':'payment_request_by_status','request_status':status});
```

or use `serializeArray()` and push new items

```
var data = form.serializeArray();
data.push({name:'op',value:'payment_request_by_status'}).push({name:'request_status',value:status});
```

then pass data

Comment: Can you please add your both the codes to the function I written in my code and post the entire function code as your answer. It will be of great help to me as well as others.

Comment: `data  : formdata ? formdata + '&' + $.param({'op':'payment_request_by_status','request_status':status}) : form.serialize() + '&' + $.param({'op':'payment_request_by_status','request_status':status}),`

Comment: I tried this code but it's giving syntax error. I think the semicolon appearing before last comma should be removed. Am I correct?

Comment: yup , sorry just forget to delete while copying

Comment: Just tell me is this line I wrote correct?
data        : formdata ? formdata : form.serialize() + '&' + $.param({'op':'upload_brand_image','id':id}),

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is, add two `hidden` fields to your already existing form, name one of them as `op` and set the value as `payment_request_by_status` and another one as `request_status` and the value based on the status.

When the form is serialized, it will automatically send these values also.