# How to call a php file from <a> tag and pass data?

Tags: php, html, forms, nav

I want to call a php function from an `<a>` tag in html.
When you click this link in I want to pass data to the php file.

I know how to do this with the `<form>` tag but the link is placed in the `<nav>` 
section of the page.

Comment: what you've done so far? please put your work here. and in this case you should use `jquery ajax` to pass data. and probably duplicate question!

Comment: thanks I will check it out!

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19438937/passing-data-with-jquery-ajax

Comment: Ajax is the medium... use that to call your php function

Comment: I'm amazed no one simply suggested to add ?var_name=value to the href...

Comment: *but the link is placed in the `<nav>` section of the page* — Why is that a problem? Nothing prevents you putting forms inside nav elements.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna pass changing data, your only option is javascript using `<a href='#' onclick='javascript:submitForm();'></a>`.
You can eighter go

### The Form Way

so the function `submitForm();` will just submit an invisible form like this:

```
<form id="form" action="/myfile.php" method="POST" style="display: none;">
    <input name="mychangingdata" value="suddenly_i_changed">
</form>
<script>
    function submitForm()
    {
         $("[name='mychangingdata']").val("now_i_changed");
         $("#form").submit(); // untested, maybe $(...)[0].submit();?
    }
</script>
```

Or while we're already using jQuery, we can just go

### The Ajax Way

Which isn't too hard:

```
<script>
function submitForm()
{
    $.post("myfile.php", {
        "mychangingddata": "now_i_changed"
    }).done(function(data){
        // Handle data
    });
}
</script>
```

### Important Note

In both ways I used jQuery. The file name has been `myfile.php` and the data submited always has been `mychangingdata: now_i_changed`. Please read the documentary of jQuery for explanation of the functions and further help.