# Uploading files with Dropzone JS into child folder

Tags: javascript, php, dropzone.js

I have a form in which I have a field for name and dropzone. So if I go with simple one like to upload files in main `upload` folder then it is working but I want to upload files in child folder like I am getting folder name through `<input type="text" name="name" />` and on upload file should go to new generated folder.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="name" class="form-control fl_name" />
<div class="dropzone"></div>
```

JS:

```
// CREATE FOLDER FOR FILE UPLOADS
$('.name-alert').hide();
$('.fl_name').on('change', function() {
    var fl_name = 'name='+ $(this).val();
    var fl_url = $(this).closest('form').attr('action');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: fl_url,
        data: fl_name,
        cache: false,
        success: function(result){
            if (result == '0') {
                $('.name-alert').slideDown();
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('.name-alert').slideUp();
                }, 2000);
            }
        }
    });
});

// CREATE DROPZONE ENVIORMENT
var myDropzone = new Dropzone('div.dropzone', {
    url: "http://localhost/build/assets/php/customer-query.php", 
    addRemoveLinks: true,       
    init: function() {
        this.on('success', function( file, resp ){
           var fl_name = 'name='+ $('.fl_name').val();
           var fl_url = 'http://localhost/build/assets/php/customer-query.php';
           $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: fl_url,
                data: fl_name,
                cache: false,
                success: function(result){
                    console.log(result);
                }
            });
        });
      },
});
```

PHP:

```
// Create Folder On Input Field Change
$fname = $_POST['name'];
if (!file_exists('../uploads/'.$fname.'/')) {
    mkdir('../uploads/'.$fname.'/', 0777, true);
} else {
    echo '0';
}

// Upload Files
$fl_name = $_POST['name'];
$ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
$storeFolder = '../uploads/'.$fl_name.'/';
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];                   
    $targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) .$ds. $storeFolder .$ds; 
    $targetFile =  $targetPath. $_FILES['file']['name']; 
    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
}
```

in my code files are still uploading in main folder instead of new folders.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your "data" in the ajax call doesn't look like a json object. Try changing it to:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: fl_url,
            data: {'name':fl_name},
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            success: function(result){
                console.log(result);
            }
        });
```

See [Passing data with jquery ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19438937/passing-data-with-jquery-ajax) if you need a further example on passing data with json via ajax

You may also be missing the following in your php file to read the json input:

```
$inputJSON = file_get_contents("php://input");
$result = json_decode($inputJSON,TRUE);
```

in which case you need to change

```
$fname = $_POST['name'];
```

to

```
$fname = $result['name'];
```

Comment: same result in my code `name=inputValue` is also passing the variable but when I am trying to pass variable in `if(!empty($_FILES)){}` it is not working. I am getting blank respond.

Comment: Do you get any errors. If I'm reading your code correctly, $ds is a directory separator and you may have to many /'s on your file path since $storeFolder = '../uploads/'.$fl_name.'/'; already has /'s on it. If I'm reading it wrong, what is $ds hold?